# What is $\frac{x^2}{|x|}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions

Why $\frac{x^2}{|x|}$ is not defined on $x=0$. It should be $0$, since $\frac{x^2}{|x|}=|x|$, isn't?

Comment: $x^2/|x| = |x|$ for all $x \neq 0$. However $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 /|x| = 0$ indeed.

Comment: Non-differentiable at 0

Comment: $f(x)= \frac xx$ is also not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Just as $f(x) = \frac{x^2 - x -6}{x-3} = \frac{(x+2)(x-3)}{x- 3} $ is not defined at $x= 3$, but for all other values, all $x\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}, f(x) = x+2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression
$$ \frac{x^2}{|x|}$$
is not defined when $x=0$.  However, we can find another expression that "does the same job" as $x^2/|x|$ and is defined at zero.  To do this, define the function
$$ f(x) := \frac{x^2}{|x|}, $$
which is not defined at zero.  On the other hand, the function
$$ g(x) := |x| $$
is defined for all real values of $x$, and $f(x) = g(x)$ whenever both functions are defined.  Thus it is reasonable to "extend" $f$ to all real numbers by setting $f(0) = 0$.  In this way, we can reasonably say that
$$ \frac{x^2}{|x|} = |x|, $$
which is zero when $x=0$.

---

At the suggestion of Henning Makholm, let us note that this $g$ is in no way unique.  I could just as easily have remarked that
$$ h(x) := \begin{cases} |x| & \text{if $x\ne 0$, and} \\
47 & \text{if $x = 0$} \\
\end{cases} $$
is equal to $f$ whenever both $h$ and $f$ are defined, therefore we could extend $f$ to all real numbers by setting $f(0) = 47$.  This approach is entirely reasonable, but somewhat unsatisfying.  We would like to extend $f$ to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ in the "nicest possible way."  What we mean by nicest possible way is nebulous, but in this context that probably means *continuity* (in other contexts it might mean smoothly, or up to a set of measure zero, or some other nonsensical mathematical gobbledygook).

That is, we would like to extend $f$ to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ so that the extended function is continuous.  The only way to to that is to set $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: "by setting f(x) = 0" -> "by setting f(0) = 0"

Comment: @ZainPatel Indeed.  I have corrected it.  Thank you.

Comment: This is a good point to make, but I think it needs some extension to really work -- in particular, why use your $g$ instead of, say, $$g_2(x) = |x|+\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{tx^2+1}$$ which also satisfies $f(x)=g_2(x)$ whenever $x\ne 0$ but has $g_2(0)=1$? The reasoning must be that your $g$ is somehow the _nicest_ qualifying $g$; in particular it is the only _continuous_ $g$ that qualifies.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are absolutely correct.  I was just hoping to sweep that under the rug.  Give me a moment...

Comment: @XanderHenderson then if $f(x)=g(x)=0$, if $x=c$, then we can assign any value of the function $f(x)/g(x)$ when $x=c$, isn't ??

Comment: @doctorme In principle, yes.  If $f(c) = g(c) = 0$, then we can assign any value we like to the ratio $f(c)/g(c)$.  Indeed, if $g(c) = 0$, even if $f(c)\ne 0$, we can define $f(c)/g(c)$ to be anything we like---$c$ is not in the domain of the ratio, so we are free.  However, in practice we would like the quotient function to have "nice" properties, such as continuity or smoothness.  This severely limits what we are able to do.

Answer (score 4):

$\dfrac{x^2}{|x|}\neq |x|$ when $x=0,\;$ since $\,\dfrac 1{|x|}\,$ is not defined at $x=0$

Comment: Please feel free to roll back to your original post.  There was absolutely no problem with your answer.  I just wanted to be consistent with the formatting of fractions, and used `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`, i.e., I used the "display style"  to get the fractions  to render larger (as they would, when `$$` is used instead of `$`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @amWhy